# How to display text next "set /p"

Tags: batch-file

Not beneath, but next to "set /p".

My code is

> set /p "input=Input: " && echo Test

What I want the output to be is

> Input: [input text here] Test

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question says "display", but does not expand upon that. Could you please define that purpose? and explain what you want the resulting variable `%input%` to contain? If you could possibly put your code into context too, instead of just one line, it would greatly assist responders too.

Comment: It would be relatively simple to have it display as you wish, however anything typed at that prompt would begin to overwrite the prompt text `Test`. Example: `For /F %%G In ('Prompt $H ^& For %%H In (1^) Do Rem') Do Set /P "input=Input:   Test%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G"`, and `For /F %%G In ('Prompt $H ^& For %%H In (1^) Do Rem') Do Set /P "input=Input: [input text here]%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G%%G"`. In both cases the content will only contain what was typed, not what is displayed.

Comment: @Compo I mean like for example "Input: 12345" and then there's text next to it that cannot be controlled by the user

Comment: How about you try the code I have given you, so that you can see exactly how it works and what happens. Both examples are single line batch file commands which require absolutely no modification.

Comment: It's `set /p` which (hardcoded) sets the cursor to the next line. You can't work around this, but you can relocate the cursor with [escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Comment: If you want `Test` to be there *before* the user inputs anything, @Compo's solution is the way to go, if it should appear *after* the user made it's input, use escape sequences (of course you should know, where exactly `Test` should appear)

Comment: @Compo: IMHO the purpose of the question is very clear: _first_ execute a `set /p` command to enter an input (_any_ input) and then, after the `set /p` command is completed, show a text _after_ the input text...

Comment: @Stephan: You can relocate the cursor with just an `echo` command and an interesting trick (that not works in Windows 10). See my answer below...

Comment: @Aacini, clearly you have read into this differently, but that does not mean that what you've read, correct or otherwise, was very clear, and I'm at fault for misunderstanding. The title and first line of the question tells me what I understood to be the most important part, **How to display text next “set /p”**, and **next to "set /p"**! Their first example shows the command `Set /P` on the same line, and directly followed by, the string `Test`. Your answer shows an `Echo` command followed by the string `Test` on the same line, so the string `Test` is not visible next to the `Set /P` prompt.

Comment: @Compo: Well, the question indicate that `set /p "input=Input: " && echo Test` show the text _beneath_ "set /p". The OP specify that he just wants the text _next_ to "set /p". This is the only requirement. The question say nothing about `Set /P` prompt. The OP even show an example: **if** "Input: 12345" **then** show the text next to it. That is, show the text _after_ the "12345" input string. There is no limit or restriction on the input string. Anyway, only the OP could clear this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in all Windows versions excepting Windows 10:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get BS, CR and TAB characters
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
set "TAB="
for /F "skip=4 delims=pR tokens=2" %%a in ('reg query hkcu\environment /v temp' ) do set "TAB=%%a"
for /F "tokens=2 delims=0" %%a in ('shutdown /? ^| findstr /BC:E') do if not defined TAB set "TAB=%%a"

set /p "input=Input: "
echo !TAB!!BS!!BS!!CR!Input: !input! Test
```

In order for Windows 10 to work you need to enable Legacy console mode.

Further details at [Move cursor to *any position* using just ECHO command](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7898)